# Randomly choosing a position from a matrix based on the value in that position

Tags: java, matrix, random

I have an XxY matrix (so it's 2D) filled with values based on the this formula with f being 200 for now:

> randomGenerator((f*10)+(f/2))+1

RandomGenerator is a random number generator from the Java.util.Random class

I want to randomly pick a position from the matrix like [2;6] and show that output to the user but I want the randomness to depend on the value of the position. If the value is higher, so is the chance it gets picked to show. Now it just shows a random position.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is the range of your numbers in the matrix? 0 to 100?

Comment: With the test as it is now it ranges from 1 to 2100 with f being 200 bit that might rise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standard approach to this problem is:

1. calculate normalized matrix from your original one
2. generate value from `0` to `1`
3. scan through normalized matrix, summarize values, when current running sum exceeds previously generated number, stop search - you found your position

normalized matrix is calcualted:

1. summarize all values from original matrix
2. fill new matrix, where every element = original element / sum of all elements

simplified example:

original array:

```
2 6 8
```

normalized matrix:

```
0.125 0.375 0.5
```

so, by generating random value `[0-1]` you will pick

```
position `0` 12.5% of time
position `1` 37.5% of time
position `2` 50% of time
```

here is the same app, which shows how it works for this example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final double[] original = new double[] { 2.0, 6.0, 8.0 };
    final double[] normalized = getNormalized(original);

    final int[] positionPicked = new int[original.length];
    final Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        final double d = rnd.nextDouble();
        final int position = getPosition(normalized, d);
        positionPicked[position]++;
    }

    for (final int p : positionPicked)
        System.out.println(p);
}

static double[] getNormalized(final double[] original) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (final double e : original)
        s += e;
    final double[] normalized = new double[original.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++)
        normalized[i] = original[i] / s;
    return normalized;
}

static int getPosition(final double[] normalized, final double v) {
    double s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < normalized.length; i++) {
        s += normalized[i];
        if (s >= v)
            return i;
    }
    return normalized.length - 1;
}
```

and results are:

```
#0  1283    12.83%
#1  3732    37.32%
#2  4985    49.85%
```

Comment: This will not be random I think. It will always go up to the highest value and then stop if i don't mistake

Comment: @BRHSM it will be random, it will stop before highest value

Comment: Let me test that BRB

Comment: Okey so i got you until you started doing things with that 0-1. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: How I can use the 1-0 in your last step to get the chance of that position being picked and also how i can write this out in code

Comment: @BRHSM re-read point #3 - it shows you have to use generated number to pick position

Comment: So the number generated should be a float

Comment: @BRHSM yes, number should be float/double

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for a second you have a list of number. You can work out the translation between list and 2d matrix.

Let's assume the probability of picking an element to be proportional.
You have this matrix

```
482  
759  
123
```

You find a way to iterate making a list, for example
4,8,2,7,5,9,1,2,3

When iterating build a cumulative sum
4, 12, 14, 21, 26, 35, 36, 38, 41

Then pick a number in the range sum*rand(), so here 0-41

The first item in cumulative sum greater than the rand number is the cell you choose.

If you want to be inversely proportional, then do your cumulative sum of 1/x the values. You can use any function of value that way.

Comment: I don't want the value. I want the position it's in. The value only resembles the chance of it getting picked

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/95linear/Matrix.java.html

This shows how the matrix is created and may help you determine a method that randomly selects a square.

(assuming that you are using the matrix class)

Comment: I am not using the matrix class I used `field = new int[x][y]`